# Any reason not to use a simple "PropertiesChanged" event when using event sourcing?

Tags: event-sourcing

I am not a big fan of event sourcing but for my current assignment it is the perfect fit. However I am still struggling with defining my commands and events. Most business applications have a lot of simple property changes originating from some UI form. If a form has 50 different properties, it makes zero sense to me to create 50 different commands resulting in 50 different command handlers and 50 different events. Surprisingly I can't find anything on the NET about this problem. All examples just update ONE property, that's not how real life is.The closest issue which comes up on searches are the problem of importing data from a CRUD system into an event sourced system.

So why not create a simple PropertiesChanged command, handler and event with just one member, a Dictionary of string and object where the Key is the property changed and the value the new value ? This would make things very easy, just one command/handler/event, also no code changes would be needed when the aggregates evolves with new properties.

Apply and replay still works, I still have a history what exactly was changed with each command.

So why is this not mentioned as the default way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

> So why is this not mentioned as the default way to do it ?

Part of the reason is certainly historic -- the communities that were first to experiment with event sourcing were already bought into [domain modeling](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html), particularly [domain driven design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), [task based user interfaces](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/).

From that perspective, treating your data like [anemic property bag](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) that you update with domain agnostic patch documents is a step in the wrong direction.

Domain driven design, in particular, tends to be applied to problems that are part of the core business of the enterprise -- those places where the company expects to derive a competitive advantage from being able to custom tune the tooling.

Put another way: if a stream of `PropertyChanged` events is good enough to meet the needs of the business, Event Sourcing is probably the wrong approach for the solution.

Comment: The only reason I use event sourcing is the fact that I need to be able to represent my aggregate at any point in time, and to make it more complex, based on the user role also by an effective date. Event sourcing solves this easy, also the second requirement as I just order my event stream by the efeective date before appying it.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask your domain expert whats going on in the business process - it is unlikey he will describe everything as a change of the property. He would tell you "Order is paid", not "Property Order.paid is set to true".

The same way, part of your system also reacts to the relevant events - shipping subsystem would be interested in the ORDER_PAID events. You can make it listen to all PROPERTY_CHANGED events and react only to those when Order.paid was set from false to true, but this at very least a processing overhead.

So I would say, when you reduce business events to property changes you are losing precious information.

Of course, the opposite extreme would be to make a separate event for every possible property - this is not good either.